# UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString Issue

Tags: iphone

I am working on UIWebView. what i want to do is to add a div into the content loaded by webview.
For that, I have written the code as follows :

```
    NSString *strInputJS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var newDiv = document.createElement('div');newDiv.innerHTML = '<h1>Hi there!</h1>';document.body.appendChild(newDiv);newDiv.style.height =  100 + 'px';"];

    NSString *strResult = [_webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:strInputJS];
```

But it is not working. I tried the same javascript with an HTML page as follows :

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>JSTrial</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.innerHTML = '<h1>Hi there!</h1>';
    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
    newDiv.style.height =  100 + 'px';
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I opened the HTML page in the Safari browser, as well as the Safari browser in iPhone Simulator. It worked well.

The web view has been already loaded at the point I am trying to inject new JS.
what I found was, newDiv.style is null.

what could be wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

note never used variable numberOfPixelsForPadding.

- check did u set delegate correctly
- call stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString in webViewDidFinishLoad

  -(void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
  {
      NSString *strInputJS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var newDiv = document.createElement('div');newDiv.innerHTML = '

  ## Hi there!

  ';document.body.appendChild(newDiv);newDiv.style.height =  100 + 'px';"];

  [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:strInputJS];

  }

NOTE :

```
NSString *strInputJS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var newDiv = document.createElement('div');newDiv.innerHTML = '<h1>Hi there!</h1>';document.body.appendChild(newDiv);newDiv.style.height =  100 +  '%ipx';",numberOfPixelsForPadding];
```

i think this will help..!!

Comment: hi Dileep, Thanks for the reply. I tried removing the unncessary argument. but the problem persists. I have modified the problem for the code change to remove the argument.

Comment: is ur javascript code is in webViewDidFinishLoad.. check webView.delegate = self;

Comment: webView.delegate is set to self. My javascript code is not in webViewDidFinishLoad, but at some point after the webView is loaded. But I have tried the JS on webViewDidFinishLoad also, same issue. Also, my JS is working till the point just before Style is being set for new Div. But it is failing at the time of accessing style. Style is null. - The same JS works fine in browser.

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567653/javascipt-not-executing-in-iphone/6567949#6567949