# Javascript not executing in iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone

I want to execute javascript code from my iPhone application using UIWebView.

But only html part is executing while javascript part is not executing. It's also not showing an error.

```
NSMutableString *htmlCode = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"<!DOCTYPE HTML>"];


[htmlCode appendString:@"<html><head><tilte> sadaf </title>"];

[htmlCode appendString:@"<h1>My First Web Page</h1>"];


[ htmlCode appendString:@" <p id='demo'>This is a paragraph.</p>"];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlCode baseURL:nil];


webView.delegate= self;

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=Date();</script>   "];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if delegate has been set correctly.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //  init and create the UIWebView
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 88, 320, 400)]; 
    webView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    webView.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
    [webView  setDelegate:self];//set the web view delegates for the web view to be itself
    NSMutableString *htmlCode = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"<!DOCTYPE HTML>"];

    [htmlCode appendString:@"<h1>My First Web Page</h1>"]; 
    [htmlCode appendString:@" <p id='demo'>This is a paragraph.</p>"]; 
    [htmlCode appendString:@"</form> </body> </html> "]; 
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlCode baseURL:nil];

    [self.view addSubview:webView];//add the web view to the content view
}

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView1
{
    NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad");
    [webView1 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"alert('hi');document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=Date();"];
}
```

This may help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` to evaluate your JavaScript, then you do not need to wrap your JavaScript code in `<script>` tags (and in fact, doing so will prevent your script from executing).  Try this:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=Date();"];
```

Comment: @mplungjan - Yes, I should have been more clear.  If you use `<script>` tags in the string you pass to `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` then your JavaScript will not be evaluated.

Comment: @aroth - then where i shuls write this code <script type='text/javascript'></scrpit>