# UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString returns empty string

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I know there have been [couple of discussion already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567653/javascript-not-executing-in-iphone/6567949#6567949) on this topic, but I am trying a different approach here.
I am trying to first inject a variable into the Webview, then try to get the output by calling a method on that variable. Here's how it goes:

```
webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:window.bounds];
[window addSubview:webview];
[webview loadHTMLString:@"<html><head><script>(function() {var myVariable = window.myVariable = {};"
 @"myVariable.getVersion = function() {return 1;}})();"
 @"</script></head></html>"
                baseURL:nil];
webview.delegate = self;

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
if ([[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"typeof(myVariable);"] isEqualToString:@"object"]) {
    NSLog(@"version=%@",[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myVariable.getVersion());"]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"failed the test.");
}
```

}

The output:
version=